# C navigate, can't compile

Tags: c

As part of a school project I have to build a program that runs the user through the rooms of the house. I am new to C so I am a bit stuck on an error that I cannot resolve.

The concept behind the program is that the user will enter direction commands through the console with numbers, the numbers signify the directions north, south, east, west.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define North 0
#define East 1
#define South 2
#define West 3

typedef struct{
    char Description[200];
    unsigned int Exit[4];
}
location;

void SetupRooms();
void DescribeRoom(unsigned int RoomNumber);
void DescribeExits(unsigned int RoomNumber);
int GetDirection(unsigned int RoomNumber);

location Room[8]; 

void main(){
    unsigned int RoomNumber=1;
    signed int Direction;
    SetupRooms();

    while(1){
        //system("cls");
        DescribeRoom(RoomNumber);
        DescribeExits(RoomNumber);
        Direction = GetDirection(RoomNumber);
        if(Direction ==-1)
        {
            printf("\n BYE BYE!\n");
            break;//exit(0);
        }
        if(Direction > 0) 
            RoomNumber = Direction;
        else 
            printf("\n You just walked into a wall! \n");
    }
}

void SetupRooms()
{
    strcpy(Room[1].Description,"Hallway. ");
    Room[1].Exit[North] =5;
    Room[1].Exit[East]  =7;
    Room[1].Exit[South] =-1;
    Room[1].Exit[West]  =2;

    strcpy(Room[2].Description,"Dining Room. ");
    Room[2].Exit[North]=4;
    Room[2].Exit[East]=1;
    Room[2].Exit[South]=0;
    Room[2].Exit[West]=3;

    strcpy(Room[3].Description, "Kitchen. ");
    Room[3].Exit[North]=-1;
    Room[3].Exit[East]=2;
    Room[3].Exit[South]=0;
    Room[3].Exit[West]=0;

    strcpy(Room[4].Description, "Main Bedroom. ");
    Room[4].Exit[North] =0;
    Room[4].Exit[East]=5;
    Room[4].Exit[South]=2;
    Room[4].Exit[West]=-1;

    strcpy(Room[5].Description, "Bathroom. ");
    Room[5].Exit[North]=0;
    Room[5].Exit[East]=6;
    Room[5].Exit[South]=1;
    Room[5].Exit[West]=4;

    strcpy(Room[6].Description, "Kids Bedroom. ");
    Room[6].Exit[North]=0;
    Room[6].Exit[East]=0;
    Room[6].Exit[South]=7;
    Room[6].Exit[West]=5;

    strcpy(Room[7].Description, "Lounge. ");
    Room[7].Exit[North]=6;
    Room[7].Exit[East]=-1;
    Room[7].Exit[South]=0;
    Room[7].Exit[West]=1 ;

}

void DescribeRoom(unsigned int RoomNumber)
{
    printf("The room you are in is the: %s",Room[RoomNumber].Description);
}

void DescribeExits(unsigned int RoomNumber)
{
    if (Room[RoomNumber].Exit[North] != -1)
        printf("To the North is the: %d",Room[RoomNumber].Exit[North]);

    else 
        printf("No Exit to the North");


    if (Room[RoomNumber].Exit[East] != -1)
        printf("To the East is the: %d",Room[RoomNumber].Exit[East]);

    else 
        printf("No Exit to the East");


    if (Room[RoomNumber].Exit[South] != -1)
        printf("To the South is the: %d",Room[RoomNumber].Exit[South]);

    else 
        printf("No Exit to the South");


    if (Room[RoomNumber].Exit[West] != -1)
        printf("To the West is the: %d",Room[RoomNumber].Exit[West]);

    else 
        printf("No Exit to the West");

}

int GetDirection(unsigned int RoomNumber)
{
    int RetVal = -1;
    char Input = _getch();
    switch(Input)
    {
    case 'n':
        RetVal = 0;
        break;
    case 's':
        RetVal = 1;
        break;
    case 'e':
        RetVal = 2;
        break;
    case 'w':
        RetVal = 3;
        break;
    }
    return RetVal;
}
```

And this is the error I get after I run it

```
;============ Building Project hose2 ============
;============ Linking ============
    Linker Error (Severity 4)
    No matching files for file specification:
    "|:\\acfs5\dt11\dt11ddf\my documents\cc386 projects\assign.prac.2.obj"
    Error: Unresolved External "_main" in Module "C:\tools\cc\clibs\platform\WIN32\pe\c0.c"
    Linker Error (Severity 255)
    Trouble opening "|:\\acfs5\dt11\dt11ddf\my documents\cc386 projects\hose2.lss" for output.
    Compile done.  Errors: 3,  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `int main()` instead of `void main()`.

Comment: What is the '|' doing in the path - shouldn't it be a drive letter ('C' etc)

Comment: Ohh... Zork! You are likely to be eaten by a Grue!

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Unresolved External "_main" in ...
```

means the linker can't find the symbol called "_main" it was looking for. The `main` function is supposed to look like this:

```
int main() { ... }
```

or, if you need command-line arguments, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }
```

For future reference, you'll get a better response if you show you tried to narrow down the problem - here you could have removed *all* your code apart from `void main() {}` and still seen the same error. That would have been a pretty strong clue.

Answer (score 0):

Your main function needs to return an integer (non-zero is interpreted as an error).